# Unable to install Ubuntu server OS via serial port

Tags: grub2

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server OS (ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso) in bare metal Micor Server (Intel Rangley / Mohon Peak Platform). My server has no onboard or offboard VGA card. I am using serial console for display purpose. I have tried different ways to install Ubuntu OS via Serial Port, but I am able to get video till grub, after that I am not getting no video. By changing grub.cfg values, Still I am not able get display.

Can you please provide me the steps to install Server OS via Serial Port?

I have shared my grub.cfg. Please view it.

```
 if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    #set gfxmode=auto
    #insmod efi_gop
    #insmod efi_uga
    #insmod gfxterm
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
    insmod vbe
    insmod font
    insmod serial
    terminal_output serial
    terminal_input serial
fi
if loadfont /boot/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
    #insmod gfxterm
    #set gfxmode=auto
    #set gfxpayload=keep
    #insmod efi_gop
    #insmod efi_uga
    #insmod gfxterm
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
    insmod vbe
    insmod font
    insmod serial
    terminal_output serial
    terminal_input serial
fi
if [ "yes" == "yes"  ] ; then
  serial --port=0x2f8 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1
  terminal_input serial
  terminal_output serial
  CONSOLE_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8"
  export CONSOLE_CMDLINE_LINUX
fi
#set menu_color_normal=white/black
#set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
set timeout=5
function onie_entry_start {
  if [ "${grub_platform}" != "efi" ] ; then
    acpi
  fi
 echo "${grub_platform}"
}
ONIE_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet ${CONSOLE_CMDLINE_LINUX} i2c-ismt.bus_speed=100 boot_env=recovery"
set default="0"
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server(text)" {
    #set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
    insmod serial
    onie_entry_start
    #linux  /casper/vmlinuz   boot=casper quiet  ---
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  vga=normal $ONIE_CMDLINE_LINUX file=/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed #vga=normal console=tty0 console=S0,115200n8 ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
}
```

I have tried changed grub.cfg with various value, Still I am not getting display. I am getting below error.

```
***error: no suitable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode
[    2.479847] ACPI Error: [\TLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.489349] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CP00._TPC, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.500349] ACPI Error: [\TLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.509836] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CP01._TPC, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.520823] ACPI Error: [\TLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.530311] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CP02._TPC, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.541295] ACPI Error: [\TLVL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.550781] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CP03._TPC, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.666302] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    2.671616] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    2.683594] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    4.961846] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    4.967821] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
mount: can't find /root in /etc/fstab
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```